# Unable to hide the x button that clears the input filed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

which I use to clear the text.  This x box always appear. I want this x box to appear only when input has focus and hide after word. Currently it appears all the time.

[image]

```
                       <div class="input-group">
                              <div class="btn-group has-feedback has-clear">
                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)
                                <a id="searchclear3"
                                   class=" a glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle  form-control- 
                                   feedback form-control-clear"
                                   style="pointer-events:auto; text-decoration:none; 
                                   cursor:pointer;"
                                   onclick="$(this).prev('input').val('');return false;">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some fancy CSS to hide the “searchclear3" element when the text box isn’t focused. The trick is to use the CSS “Adjacent Sibling Selector”, `+`. (Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator))

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="btn-group has-feedback has-clear">
        <input id="txtInput" type="text"/>
        <a id="searchclear3"
           class=" a glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle  form-control-
                                   feedback form-control-clear"
           style="pointer-events:auto; text-decoration:none;
                                   cursor:pointer;"
           onclick="alert('click'); return false;">X
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that for convenience, I hard-coded the markup for the text box, put an “X” in the `a` element and fudged the `onclick` handler. You’ll have to figure out an appropriate selector for the text box and get rid of the other stuff.

**CSS**

```
input#txtInput + a#searchclear3 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
input#txtInput:focus + a#searchclear3 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Those rules say that an `a` element with `id` “searchclear3” that is a sibling of an `input` whose `id` is “txtInput” should be visible when the `input` has focus, and hidden otherwise.

Comment: HI Padeso, what you mean by appropriate selector?

Comment: If you create the text input with `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)` Razor will generate the `id` field, and it won’t be easy to use it in the CSS. You could to assign a `class` to the element instead, and use that in the CSS rule.